# Make in formation boxes with javascript and CSS

Tags: javascript, css, web

I would like to make information boxes like this one:

http://mmarfil.com/
[mouseover to see]

Comment: Just don't execute it like this site did, because users may not know to ever hover over it, making the page appear ... meaningless.  To prove my point, you had to tell us what to do.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular site uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) fadeIn and fadeOut to show an image (an actual png) of the tooltip like this:

```
$('.toggle').hover(
        function(){
            $('#baloon').fadeIn('normal');
        }, function() {
            $('#baloon').fadeOut('normal');
});
```

The image is positioned above the box using the css fixed positioning:

```
position: fixed;
margin-left: X px;
margin-top: Y px;
```

Similar results can be achieved using html, positioning a div instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

You only need CSS for that...

CSS:

```
a:link,
a:visited {
position:relative;
text-decoration:none;
}

a .tooltip img {
border:none;
}

.tooltip {
width:300px;
position:absolute;
bottom:100%;
margin:0 0 7px 0;
padding:15px;
font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal;
text-align:left;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
line-height:1.5;
border:solid 1px;
-moz-border-radius:7px;
-webkit-border-radius:7px;
border-radius:7px;
-moz-box-shadow:
0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3),
0 1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.5) inset;
-webkit-box-shadow:
0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3),
0 1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.5) inset;
box-shadow:
0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3),
0 1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.5) inset;
cursor:default;
display:block;
visibility:hidden;
opacity:0;
z-index:999;
-moz-transition:all 0.4s linear;
-webkit-transition:all 0.4s linear;
-o-transition:all 0.4s linear;
transition:all 0.4s linear;
}

.tooltip:before,
.tooltip:after {
width:0;
height:0;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
margin:0 0 -20px -10px;
border:solid 10px;
border-color:transparent;
display:table-cell;
content:"";
}

.tooltip:before {
margin:0 0 -24px -12px;
border:solid 12px;
border-color:transparent;
z-index:-1;
}

/* hover */

a:hover .tooltip {
text-decoration:none;
visibility:visible;
opacity:1;
-moz-transition:all 0.2s linear;
-webkit-transition:all 0.2s linear;
-o-transition:all 0.2s linear;
transition:all 0.2s linear;
}
```

CSS color-scheme class:

```
.tooltip.green {
color:#445400;
background:#8DB600;
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(141,182,0,0.8),rgba(141,182,0,1));
background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(rgba(141,182,0,0.8)),to(rgba(141,182,0,1)));
border-color:#7C9902;
}
```

Usage:

```
<a href="#">bistre<span class="tooltip green">THIS IS A TOOOOOLTIPP!!!/span></a>
```